# How to add an existing git repository (without an eclipse project) into eclipse?

Tags: python, eclipse, git, pydev, egit

I have a local git repository which has some Python modules and I would like to create a new project which includes these files (I installed egit egit).
My repository does not include a .project file.

Comment: If all else fails, you can always create an empty project, copy over the dot files and directories (.project, but some plugins may create more) to your existing repository and than import it into eclipse as existing project.

Comment: nice idea, but is there any more straight forward way?

Answer (score 5):

It happened to me not so long ago. 
I could not find a nice way to solve it, but found a simple way though :).

What I did was simple :
Create a brand new project, and let it empty. 
Get the .project file wihch was created together with the project and add it in the git repository.

Now you can directly import your repo as a project.

Quite straightforward and simple.

Comment: After spending lots of time searching for the 'right' way to do it, this did the trick. thanks! (+1)

Comment: In my case, since it is a Java project, I also copied the auto-generated `.classpath` and the `.settings` folder, and everything worked. If you push to a remote, remember to add a `.gitignore` to avoid pushing back those files (including `.project`) to the remote. Also after copying but before importing the repo, I delete the temporarily created project to avoid having two projects with the same name.

Comment: I do it the same way but instead of creating an empty project I copy and paste the .project and .pythonproject files from some existing project and edit them in a text editor

Answer (score 1):

I was also confused by this, and found the User Guide unhelpful.

I found the answer here: http://www.eclipse.org/forums/index.php/m/757705/

It is quite simple: you have to change the location in the "New Java Project" wizard, from the default location in your workspace to the folder in the cloned repository (probably `~/git/name_of_repo`).

Answer (score 1):

1. File > New PyDev Project
2. Unclick "Use default" and browse to your git repo.
3. Enter project name.  Name ***must*** be the same as the git repo.  You'll get a "Source Folder Not Found" error if it's not.
4. Click Finish.